# echarts hide xaxis and ticks

Tags: javascript, echarts

How can I hide xaxis and ticks in echarts? The closest I have come is setting the color to the page color but the ticks still show in gray:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  splitLine:{ 　　　　show:false 　　},
  axisLabel: {
    textStyle: {
        color: 'white'
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try expanding on your Series options:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  splitLine:{ show: false },
  axisLine: { show: false },
  axisTick: { show: false },
  axisLabel: { show: false }
  },
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/13c2d062e6bcd49ab6da87eb4032ac01ec9fe467/src/coord/axisDefault.ts) are the defaults